# log4net write file is ok but cant insert to database

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

This is my configuration file contains log4net attributes, if I use "RollingLogFileAppender" appender it writes file correctly but I am using
"AdoNetAppender" and expect to see same string in message column of inserted row. But somehow this not work..

(table defination and query configurations are from apache documentation so it cant be wrong I though connection string is my problem, But application already have connection with the same db I also shared the connection string is being used by adonet)

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\\AkisLog\\Logs.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="100" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="data source=******\SQLTEST;initial catalog=LISANSSIZ_SANTRAL_PROJE_ONAY;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=pwd" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>


 ...
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TedasDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Project.csdl|res://*/Project.ssdl|res://*/Project.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****\SQLTEST;initial catalog=LISANSSIZ_SANTRAL_PROJE_ONAY;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And .cs file:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
{
    log.Error("Error ocurred here");
}

if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
{
    log.Debug("Debug message");
}
```

Comment: Make sure the caller has permissions to write to the database. Also enable log4net internal debugging, and have a look at the output of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buffersize is 100, which means that messages will be written after 100 messages. Change it to 1, it will flush the messages directly to the sql database:

```
 <bufferSize value="1" />
```

If that does not work, enable log4net interal debugging to see if you have connection problems. Also check if you have the latest version of log4net.